# Trigger.io: Missing entitlements when building with ad-hoc certificate

Tags: trigger.io

Recently tried to get wireless distribution of Trigger.io apps going, as described here:

http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/best_practice/wireless_distribution.html

Unfortunately, these apps (built with a provisioning profile dedicated as "Ad Hoc") mysteriously fail to install when distributed over the web. An investigation of the syslog output from the device shows that the get-task-allow entitlement is missing. A similar error appears when attempting to drop the resulting IPA files onto the Testflight mac app for uploading.

Can I provide a custom entitlements plist through some obscure command line flag? Or should the platform use the correct ones automatically when it detects an "enterprise" build?

Answer (score 2):

The `get-task-allow` entitlement is what controls if the app is debuggable. It should be set to false in ad-hoc and distribution provisioning profiles.

Have a look in the ad-hoc profile you used to package your app: you should see something like:

```
<key>get-task-allow</key>
<false/>
```

That should also make its way into the binary after it's built. Quick and dirty check: unzip the IPA in `release/ios` and grep for `get-task-allow` in the binary. I get:

```
<key>get-task-allow</key><false/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when I try to sideload the resulting ipa onto a device using the "ideviceinstaller" command line tool, I get the following output in the device's syslog:

Comment: Apr 10 00:45:39 Benglert-N41 installd[53] <Error>: entitlement 'keychain-access-groups' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
Apr 10 00:45:39 Benglert-N41 installd[53] <Error>: entitlement 'get-task-allow' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
Apr 10 00:45:39 Benglert-N41 installd[53] <Error>: entitlement 'application-identifier' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile

Comment: I came across this problem when attempting to upload an IPA to Test Flight, I took the quick and dirty approach. Using a text editor I opened the Ad-Hoc Distribution profile changed:

    `<key>get-task-allow</key><false/>`

to

    `<key>get-task-allow</key><true/>`

Then rebuilt the IPA and it worked.